# Pyspark Dataframe GroupBy Count is Different Every Time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark so I feel like I'm missing something simple and stupid here but I am missing it. I read the contents of a parquet file into a spark dataframe. Then I groupby a binary column and count the results. The numbers are different every time. Is this an issue of syncing data between spark nodes or does this have something to do with the lazy execution or am I just missing some basic fundamental spark principle? I'm very confused by these results.

```
df = spark.read.parquet(input_file)
df = df.limit(2000)
print(df.count())
print(df.groupBy('STATUS').count().collect())
print(df.groupBy('STATUS').count().collect())
print(df.groupBy('STATUS').count().collect())

>>> 2000
>>> [Row(STATUS=0, count=1613), Row(STATUS=1, count=387)]
>>> [Row(STATUS=0, count=1528), Row(STATUS=1, count=472)]
>>> [Row(STATUS=0, count=1646), Row(STATUS=1, count=354)]
```

Below is the df schema:

```
root
 |-- GRP_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- WEK_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- WEK_BGN_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- WEK_END_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FEATURES: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- STATUS: long (nullable = true)
```

I should also note that if I convert the spark dataframe to pandas and get a count, it works just fine:

```
dfp = df.toPandas()    
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 0].count())
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 1].count())
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 0].count())
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 1].count())
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 0].count())
print(dfp['STATUS'][dfp['STATUS'] == 1].count())

>>> 1494
>>> 506
>>> 1494
>>> 506
>>> 1494
>>> 506
```

Comment: How is the column `STATUS` defined? Does it depend on other rows? Can you share the schema of your DataFrame (`df.printSchema()`)?

Comment: STATUS is a static binary column in a static 2000 row dataset. It does not depend on other rows. Each row is an independent observation with a STATUS of either 0 or 1. I've added the schema to the OP.

Comment: Instead of calling `collect()` at the end can you run, `df.groupby('STATUS').count().show()` to see what the results are?

Comment: I made an edit to my code as I missed something that might be important here. My apologies. To get a 2000 row dataset I am using the limit method.

Comment: @vealkind - I tried that and it just displays differently but the same problem exists.

Comment: @MGriggs using limit is the reason then. You won't get the same `2000` entries each time, unless you specify a deterministic order by (DataFrames are not ordered).

Comment: @pault - yeah makes sense the more I read about limit. The documentation is a little light and I didn't think about it till after but... is this because of the lazy execution? So every time I run .count().collect() it goes back and reruns the .limit(2000) and pulls a new dataframe?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: df.cache() after the limit(2000) will cache the results after the first action and it will stop executing the limit each time.  I mention this just as possibly interesting, not as a best practice.